# Recursive search for directory returning incorrect value

Tags: qt, recursion, qdir

Having a problem returning the correct value from a recursive search for a directory. The code is below

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDir>
#include <QString>

#include <QDebug>

static QString findDirectoryPathFromId(const QString &startPath, const QString &id)
{
    QDir dir(startPath);

    QFileInfoList list = dir.entryInfoList(QDir::AllDirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::NoSymLinks);

    QString path;

    foreach(QFileInfo dinfo, list)
    {
        if (dinfo.fileName() == id)
        {
            qDebug() << "****************Found****************" << dinfo.filePath();
            return dinfo.filePath();

        }

        else
        {
            findDirectoryPathFromId(dinfo.absoluteFilePath(), id);
       }

    }

return QString();

}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    QStringList args = app.arguments();

    QString path = findDirectoryPathFromId("/home/project/dirtest", args.at(1));

    qDebug() << "Return path" << path;

    return 0;
}
```

The function finds the directory as the "Found" debug statement is printed, however the return value is a null string.

Could someobody explain what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I've fixed it.

I need to check if the recursive call has found the directory and return it.

```
 path = findDirectoryPathFromId(dinfo.absoluteFilePath(), id);

        if (!path.isNull())
            return path;
```

Is this correct.